# Error: any_cast<T>(any&&) broken on Windows but works in Linux

Tags: c++, maven, visual-c++

First of all, I'm a C++ novice so be gentle. In my cross-platform project I've run into an issue I can't sort out using VS Studio 2019 via the nar builder in Maven. The build works a-ok on Linux, but on Windows 10 x64 the build fails here:

```
[ERROR] OUTPUT>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\any(429): error C2338: any_cast<T>(any&&) requires T to be constructible from remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<T>>
[INFO] OUTPUT>c++/SRTServer.cpp(188): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_Ty &std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection>&>(std::any &&)' being compiled
[INFO] OUTPUT>        with
[INFO] OUTPUT>        [
[INFO] OUTPUT>            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection> &
[INFO] OUTPUT>        ]
```

The NetworkConnection is in an included h file and consists of

```
class NetworkConnection {
public:
    NetworkConnection();
    virtual ~NetworkConnection();
    std::any object;
    uint16_t connectorId;
};
```

Lines 183-193 of SRTServer.cpp

```
void gotData(ElasticFrameProtocol::pFramePtr &rPacket) {
    std::cout << "Got NAL-units of size " << unsigned(rPacket->mFrameSize) <<
                " pts " << unsigned(rPacket->mPts) << " is broken? " << rPacket->mBroken << 
                " from EFP connection " << unsigned(rPacket->mSource) << std::endl;
    // TODO the NetworkConnection must be looked up to get the server id and client id
    auto nc = std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection> &>(rPacket->mSource); // the source being a NetworkConnection is a guess right now
    // get the client from the network connection
    auto client = std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<Client> &>(nc->object);
    // call the receive method
    recvData(rPacket->pFrameData, rPacket->mFrameSize, client->serverId, client->connectorId, rPacket->mStream);
}
```

Comment: Show us line 188 of `c++/SRTServer.cpp` and the context around it.

Comment: @cdhowie coming right up

Comment: Is there a reason you are casting to a reference? I suspect that `std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection>>(rPacket->mSource)` (note no ampersand) would work.

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense to me. It seems that `rPacket->mSource` is some integral type, not a `std::any` nor a `shared_ptr` (otherwise I don't see how `unsigned(rPacket->mSource)` a couple lines up would compile). So `std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection>>(rPacket->mSource)` takes that integer, wraps it into a temporary `std::any`, then attempts to extract a `shared_ptr` from that. Even if you get it to compile, it should throw `bad_any_cast` at runtime. What **is** the type of `rPacket->mSource`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik here is the entire h file for EFP https://pastebin.com/WnvCnww8 if that helps

Comment: `SuperFrame::mSource` is of type `uint8_t`. In light of this, `std::any_cast<std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection> &>(rPacket->mSource)` doesn't make any sense. It creates a temporary `std::any` instance holding a `uint8_t`, then attempts to extract a `shared_ptr` from it. I'm not sure what kind of information you hope to extract from that one byte.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the casting of mSource (uint8_t) to a NetworkConnection (Class) will fail. And as you say -> `// the source being a NetworkConnection is a guess right now`.

There is probably another part of the code where you should do the casting. If more code is provided then we can help.

/Anders

Comment: I ended up just using the shared pointer without messing with any_cast

Comment: Yes. 'any' is great if you allow others pass C++ context trough your code like void* for C.. However if you own the full codebase the use cases for 'any' is limited and what you use makes more sense.